# Using jsDraw2DX, drawn elements do not appear unless an alert is encountered

Tags: javascript

Using jsDraw2DX, I am trying to use a series on concentric circles to display a position upon a floor plan. An array holds all drawn circles to permit clean removal. The original plan was to have them appear one-by-one, stay for 5 seconds, then to disappear one-by-one. I backed off of that due to troubles with setTimeout, and decided that just the circles image was enough, provided it could stay for a bit, then disappear, ready for the next locate operation. In the stripped down code below, The circles draw OK and remove OK, provided the one alert (marked in the code) is present, but not otherwise.

1. How might I make this work in the case that no alert was present?
2. How might I add a 5 second delay before removal?
3. How might it also work with an additional slight delay between drawing or removing each circle?

   CTest

   ```
   var oldCircle = new Array;
   var iter = 0;
   var rad = 4;

   document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);

   function printMousePos(e) {
     var cursorX = e.clientX-10;
     var cursorY = e.clientY-10;

     //alert("clicked:  X: " + cursorX + " Y: " + cursorY);
     rad = 4;
     animateLocator(cursorX, cursorY);

   }

   function animateLocator(x, y) {
     //alert("Entered animateLocator: rad: "+rad+" x: "+x+" y: "+y);
     var start = new Date().getTime();
     //alert("starting push");

     pushall(rad, x, y);
     iter = 0;
     //for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
     //  pushFunc(rad+i*4, x, y);
     //}   

     alert("starting pop"); // This alert box makes it work OK; otherwiudse nothing appears.
     setTimeout(popall(), 2000);
   }

   function pushall(rad, x, y) {
     iter = 0;
     for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
       pushFunc(rad+i*4, x, y);
     }   
   }

   function popall() {
     iter = 0;
     for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
       popFunc();
     }
   }

   function pushFunc(rad, x, y) { oldCircle.push(drawCircle(rad, x, y)); }   
   function popFunc() { oldCircle.pop().remove(); }

   function drawCircle(rad, x, y) {
     iter++;
     //alert("drawCircle rad: "+rad+" x: "+x+" y: "+y);
     //Create jxColor object
     var col = new jxColor("red");

     //Create jxPen object
     var pen = new jxPen(col,'2px');

     //Create jsGraphics object
     var gr = new jxGraphics(document.getElementById("graphics"));      
     var ctr = new jxPoint(x,y);
     var cir = new jxCircle(ctr, rad+iter*4, pen);
     //alert("after jxcircle");
     cir.draw(gr);
     //alert("after draw");
     return cir;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fyrwHZVaqLAp1JtUqulA?p=preview)

Remove the alert and Change:

```
setTimeout(popall(), 2000);
```

To:

```
setTimeout(popall, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank You so very much. It works and I can proceed to the real work. It is so very annoying when you have it so close, but are using newer tools, and have not all the depth of detail which fluency provides. You know it is one small thing, but which one? Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean. Actually i know nothing about jsDraw2DX:)